# How do I get Cordova 3.0 to recognize my own plugins in external project folders?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am able to create a Cordova 3.0 project for Android using the platform specific tools (I tried the CLI approach but could not make it work). I added the standard core plugins using the `plugman` tool. My app's `index.html` and `.js` plugin files seem to be loading since I can see the start screen and do some basic things in the app. However, the advanced functions like calling out to the database and such are not working since these were implemented by me with my own custom plugins. These plugins exist in their project folders, and are added as library references in the main activity (the one I right click in Eclipse and select `Debug as Android application`). As such, they show up as `.jar` references in the `Android Dependencies` section of the `Java Build Path` for that specific project. I am about 90% certain my `.js` plugin files are correctly setup since I do have one plugin that is a package in the main activity's `src` tree. This is the only plugin that did work. When I removed that package to test and tried using that plugin functionality, it failed to work.

My plugins have been added correctly to the `config.xml` file. At least for the one custom plugin that exists in the main activity's `src` directory. Here is an example of a non-working plugin:

```
<feature name="DBHelper_Plugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.cordova.plugin.dbhelper.DBHelper_Plugin" />
</feature>
```

Is it possible to use 3rd party plugins from external folders? If so, how? If not, do I have any alternative options other than cluttering up my main activity's `src` tree with a million plugin packages (as it is right now with the core plugins)?

Comment: Strange you couldn't manage to use the CLI (i find CLI is much easier than using plugman). How are your personal plugins? (following plugman structure with plugin.xml?)

Comment: But at the end I think everything is copied to the project when you use plugman or the cli if that's what's bothering you. I think jars have to be in the "libs" folder of the project to be seen by Android.

Comment: @QuickFix Thanks for your suggestions. I am not using a `plugin.xml` file for my plugins, I did not think they were needed since I am not installing them through `plugman`. I did try taking the `.jar` file of the `DBHelper_Plugin` and putting it into the main activity's `libs` directory and it worked (the `.jar` file also got included in the `Android Private Libraries`). I guess my question now is this, is it possible to add those library `.jar` files as links, instead of copying them over? Just to be clear, I was able to use my plugin without a `plugin.xml` file.

Comment: You're right, plugin.xml is for plugman and not needed if you're modifying all the files yourself like you do. About linking, if you're talking about commands like `ln -s`, I see no reason why it would not work. Maybe there's a way to make it work without OS linking by configuring something in eclipse, but I remember having issues in the past when jars were outside libs folder.

Comment: @QuickFix Nevermind, that was a stupid question. I just dragged the `.jar` file from the `bin` folder of the plugin project directory and Eclipse gave me an option to link to the file instead of copying it. Problem solved. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might also be having this issue, here is what I did:

1. Remove your external (outside of your main activity's `src` directory) plugins from the Android library references (right click main activity > Properties > Android > remove from `Library` section). Only do this for the plugin projects themselves.
2. Find your generated plugin `.jar` files in their `bin` directories in their respective project folders in Windows Explorer. If they are not there, build the projects in Eclipse. Drag these into the `libs` folder of your main activity. Eclipse will ask if you want to copy or link these files. Choose to link it.
3. And that's it. The plugins will now show under `Android Private Libraries` instead of `Android Dependencies`, and Cordova is able to see and use them (make sure to include them as `feature` references in your `config.xml` file). Since they are linked you can make changes to your plugin in Eclipse and not have to worry about copying it over again.

Cheers.